# Grouping a database query

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a value from list by change. The list is a query from an oracle database and has the following values:-

```
22  
22  
22  
22 
22
22
23
23
23
23
22
22
22
```

How would you code it so the output is e.g

```
22
23
22
```

I've tried loops and unique values , surely there is a simple method?

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to answer the question. How is this value changing? How are you getting it in the first place, and how are you seeing updates? What did your trial of "loops and unique values" look like, and why did it not work?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(inputsequence):
    print key
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the error 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @user2262031: What is `inputsequence` then? Don't call this on each row, pass in the Oracle cursor object instead.